# Display element for phones and tablets without CSS and only JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two different menu's that I want to show based if they are on

- phone, tablets landscape
- phone, tablets landscape portrait
- desktop

I want to do it in javascript and not CSS. So far I have:

```js
//For tablets/phones in landscape
if (window.matchMedia("(orientation: landscape)").matches) {
  return (
    <MegaMenuContainer provider={provider}/> 
  );
}
//for desktop
else if (width > 768){
  return (
    <MegaMenuContainerDesktop provider={provider}/>    
  );
}
//for tablets/phones in portrait
else {
  return (
    <MegaMenuContainer provider={provider}/>        
  );
}
```

Problem is that in the code in the first IF statement, it will be true for tablets as I want it to be. Problem is that it will ALSO be true when people uses a desktop in landscape (which is true in most cases) and the mobile menu will be shown. Any help?

Comment: Please [search](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+detecting+tablet+or+mobile) before posting. More on searching [here](/help/searching).

Comment: A lot of these code I have in the example is from a search I have found on this site. I could only find solutions for landscape/portrait detection but not for device or how to embedd this with desktop alternative.